# "npm start" command for ReactJS throwing errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So I have a 2 months old react project and some time ago I have reinstalled my Windows and now installed NodeJS and create-react-app. When I try going into the folder and running it via `npm start`, it throws me the error like in the image below. Same happens when I create a new react app and try to run it. Any ideas what it could be?

[errors in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg0nc.png)

Errors I get logged:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v9.3.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle transcendence@0.1.0~prestart: transcendence@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle transcendence@0.1.0~start: transcendence@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle transcendence@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle transcendence@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\phoon(\Desktop\transcendence\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\phoon(\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\phoon(\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\phoon(\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle transcendence@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\phoon(\Desktop\transcendence
10 silly lifecycle transcendence@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle transcendence@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle transcendence@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: transcendence@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid transcendence@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\phoon(\Desktop\transcendence
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v9.3.0
19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error transcendence@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the transcendence@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: The script is not compatible with your username

Comment: have you tried to first run `npm install` command?

Comment: is your folder name `phoon(` ? seems like the `(` in the end is causing problems